# Monotouch - ReloadData()

Tags: xamarin.ios

does anybody here know a good example in the internet using Monotouch and UITableViewController with ReloadData() or can post a code example?

Claudio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of articles and examples using UITableViewControllers at [MonoTouch.info](http://monotouch.info).  There is also an entire chapter devoted to displaying data using tables in the [Wrox MonoTouch Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/047063782X).