# MonoTouch, change tableview data

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I am using a grouped tableview to present data. I am new to MonoTouch so i have been following examples and tutorials to get started.

Now i have a UITableView, filled up with data, and want to change the data in the tableview. How can i do that, preferably in a "cost effective" way (where the cost is the phones resources).

I have two classes for populating the tableview, TableSource and TableItem. The class TableSource extends UITableViewSource.
TableSource have the following methods: int NumberOfSections, int RowsInSection, string TitleForHeader, void RowSelected, UITableViewCell GetCell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the underlying data source for your table, then call the ReloadData() method of your tableview.  This will redraw the table with the updated data.

See also: [Monotouch - ReloadData()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514783/monotouch-reloaddata)

Comment: Thank you for your response! That's definitively a way, i just figured it would be a "waste of resources" to have to reload the entire TableView just to change one value...

Comment: That's the only way I know of.  It will only be expensive if your TableSource is doing something expensive.  The TableView itself is fairly optimized to only draw the things that are visible.